# "(400) Wrong input. Some domains are invalid" while sending csv

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, backend

H. I need to send csv file via ajax. I wrote this code

```
    $('#send-csv').click(function(){
        var CSRF_TOKEN = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute("content");

        var files =$('#csv-file')[0].files;
            console.log(files);
        if(files.length > 0){
                var fd = new FormData();

                fd.append('file',files[0]);
                fd.append('_token',CSRF_TOKEN);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('api.send-csv') }}",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: fd,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        alert("send");
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(response){
                            console.log("error : " + JSON.stringify(response) );
                    }
                });
        }else{
                alert("Please select a file.");
        }

});
```

and html

```
    <div class="col-12 mt-3">
        <input type="file" class="btn btn-light" id="csv-file">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-2">
        <span class="btn btn-primary" id="send-csv">Wyślij plik CSV</span>
    </div>
```

Problem is in backend on Laravel. All the time I have an error "(400) Wrong input. Some domains are invalid". The controlle'sr method currently has no validation or business logic. It simply returns a string.

```
    public function readCSV(Request $request)
    {
        return 'test';
    }
```

How can I send correclty a csv file to my controller's method in order to read them?

Comment: Can't find anything on that error message online, so I would suspect this is not a "general" laravel error, but pertaining to some processing of the CSV data content(?). Are you sure you are looking at the correct controller method here to begin with? `route('api.send-csv')` and `public function readCSV` doesn't exactly sound like they'd correspond to each other ...?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. I can't find this error too so I ask question here. I have this error allways - it does not matter whether I send a file or not. Is this not a problem with the use of FormData?